# Is there a way to organize windows/screens in Qt Creator's Designer?

Tags: qt, qt-creator, qt-designer

Currently I'm looking at a zillion objects all over the screen that's all coordinated in the code, but I would like a way to organize things into screen1, screen2, screen3, etc, and switch between them in designer. Is there a way to do that? I figured there would be, considering with any more than a couple screens displaying simultaneously, it'll get complicated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It'll be good if Qt creator could provide that kind of feature.

For now, Qt creator already groups all .ui files into an abstract folder called "Forms" in the sidebar of Edit screen. There you can simply switch between different .ui files, and it just cost you one more click to go back the Edit screen.

Another substitution is using the combobox on top of Designer screen to switch between .ui files which are already open.

Comment: Great idea! How would I call the UI variable of different class?

Comment: If you design different UI classes (in Qt we call them "widgets") in separate .ui files, then "UI cariables" must be called by the class itself (they have their own namespace). To connect them, simply use signal-slot mechanism. I am not sure if this is what you want. I thought you just need multiple windows to organize your forms. Maybe make your purpose a little bit more clear?

Comment: That's what I need, but now I can't chose which window to show. The closest I got is something like this: `ui->setupUi(this);  Ui::test ui2;  ui2.setupUi(this);`, but now I can't get the original ui to show.

Comment: I found a way! To change windows, it just took this (aside from the "ui_login.h" include): `void WelcomeScreen::on_pushButton_2_clicked(){ Ui::Login login_ui; login_ui.setupUi(this);}` So now when I click, it runs `setupUi(this)` which causes it to display on the current window. This is perfect. I can continue now. Thanks.

Comment: Wow you had your own way! Your case makes me think of the hyperlink in a web browser, which changes the whole screen into another.